# Running MobileSafari.app in the iPhone Simulator with a url from the command line

Tags: ios, mobile, safari

Is there a way running  MobileSafari.app in the iPhone Simulator with a url from the command line?

like:

`$ open -a MobileSafari http://www.google.com`

Comment: xcrun simctl openurl xxxxxx